# Вывод данных, принадлежащих выбранной строке JTable

Tags: java, swing

Есть таблица, отображающая данные из БД. Пользователь выделяет любую строку, одну, в JTable и данные, находящиеся в этой строке, поочередно выводятся на экран (с помощью `System.out.println()`). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

DataBaseTableModel:

```
public class DataBaseTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

Connection connection;              
Statement statement;               
ResultSet resultSet;
ResultSetMetaData metaData;

String[] columnNames = {};          
Vector rows = new Vector();         

public DataBaseTableModel(String url, String driverName, String user, String passwd) {
try {
    Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    System.out.println("Opening db connection");

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url, user, passwd);   

    statement = connection.createStatement();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("Cannot find the database driver classes.");
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("Cannot connect to this database.");
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
 }

@Override
public int getRowCount() {                 
    return rows.size();
}
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {                           
     return columnNames.length;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {           
if (columnNames[column] != null) {
    return columnNames[column];         
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int aRow, int aColumn) {   
    Vector row = (Vector)rows.elementAt(aRow);         
    return row.elementAt(aColumn);
}

public void close() throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("Closing db connection");
    resultSet.close();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {    
    try {
        return metaData.isWritable(column+1);           
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    int type;
    try {
        type = metaData.getColumnType(column+1);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        return super.getColumnClass(column);
    }

    switch(type) {
    case Types.CHAR:        
    case Types.VARCHAR:
    case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
        return String.class;

    case Types.BIT:
        return Boolean.class;

    case Types.TINYINT:
    case Types.SMALLINT:
    case Types.INTEGER:
        return Integer.class;

    case Types.BIGINT:
        return Long.class;

    case Types.FLOAT:
    case Types.DOUBLE:
        return Double.class;

    case Types.DATE:
        return java.sql.Date.class;

    default:
        return Object.class;
    }
}

public String dbRepresentation(int column, Object value) {
int type;

if (value == null) {
    return "null";
}

try {
    type = metaData.getColumnType(column+1);                
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    return value.toString();
}

switch(type) {
case Types.INTEGER:
case Types.DOUBLE:
case Types.FLOAT:
    return value.toString();                             
case Types.BIT:
    return ((Boolean)value) ? "1" : "0";
case Types.DATE:                        
    return value.toString();
default:
    return "\""+value.toString()+"\"";                  
}

}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
try {
    String tableName = metaData.getTableName(column+1);         
    if (tableName == null) {
        System.out.println("Table name returned null.");
    }
    String columnName = getColumnName(column);              
    String query =  "update "+tableName+                    
            " set "+columnName+" = "+dbRepresentation(column, value)+
            " where ";
   for(int col = 0; col < getColumnCount(); col++) {                        
       String colName = getColumnName(col);
           if (colName.equals("")) {
               continue;
            }
            if (col != 0) {
                query = query + " and ";
            }
            query = query + colName +" = "+
                dbRepresentation(col, getValueAt(row, col));
        }
    System.out.println(query);
    System.out.println("Not sending update to database");
     statement.executeQuery(query);
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println("Update failed");
}
Vector dataRow = (Vector)rows.elementAt(row);                               
dataRow.setElementAt(value, column);
}

public void executeUpdate(String query) {
    if (connection == null || statement == null) {
        System.err.println("There is no database to execute the query.");
        return;
    }
    try {
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);            
        metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();           

        int numberOfColumns =  metaData.getColumnCount();    
        columnNames = new String[numberOfColumns];
        for(int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
            columnNames[column] = metaData.getColumnLabel(column+1);    
        }

        rows = new Vector();                                            
        while (resultSet.next()) {                                      
            Vector newRow = new Vector();                               
            for (int i = 1; i <= getColumnCount(); i++) {       
            newRow.addElement(resultSet.getObject(i));      
            }                                                           
            rows.addElement(newRow);                            
        }
        fireTableChanged(null);                                        
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}}
```

JРanel с таблицей во фрейме:

```
dbtm = new DataBaseTableModel( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//" + host + ":" + port + "/" + serviceName + "", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", user, passwd);
dbTablePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    dbTable = new JTable(dbtm);
    dbTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(dbTable,  ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    dbTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    dbTableScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420, 200));
    dbtm.executeUpdate(DEFAULT_QUERY);
    dbTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);//запрещает перемещать столбцы

    dbTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {//двойной шелчок
                int row = dbTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint()); //путь попроще без selectionMode
                if (row > -1) {
                    int realRow = dbTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    System.out.println(realRow);//номер строки из модели данных
        //здесь должна быть выборка объекта из модели по номеру строки и его отображение
                }
            }
        }
    });

    dbTablePanel.add(dbTableScrollPane, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 3, 1, 2,
            1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
            new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, у тебя должна быть модель, в которой переопределён метод [getValueAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29). Следовательно, тебе надо отловить действие выделение и найти индекс выделенной строки. Устанавливаешь модель выбора при помощи [setSelectionMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSelectionMode%28int%29). Константы [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION). При помощи [getSelectedRows()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRows%28%29) получаешь индексы выделенных строк. Далее преобразуешь их в исходные (если есть сортировка) при помощи [convertRowIndexToView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView%28int%29). Отлавливать действия множественной выборки не рекомендую, запутаешься сразу. Зато можно довольно легко отловить нажатие на левую кнопку мыши:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) //двойной шелчок
        {
            int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint()); //путь попроще без selectionMode
            if (row > -1) {
                int realRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row)); //номер строки из модели данных
            //здесь должна быть выборка объекта из модели по номеру строки и его отображение

        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: @LEQADA Вопрос изменен, добавил свой код

Comment: @СашаСеменец, ответ сей не мой. Но чем он не решил проблему?

Comment: решил, спасибо большое)

Comment: @LEQADA а можно как то полученные данные из строки переместить в другой класс и присвоить их например JTextField?

Comment: @СашаСеменец, в другом классе сделайте `String` переменную и отправляйте сеттеру значение. А потом выводите в `JTextField`

Answer (score 0):

Я все решил вот так:

```
if(currentQuery == "SELECT deptno id_подразделения, dname имя_подразделения, loc местоположение FROM SCOTT.DEPT ORDER BY deptno"){
        dbTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {//одинарный шелчок
                int row = dbTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int column = dbTable.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                //путь попроще без selectionMode
                if (row > -1) {
                    int realRow = dbTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    int realColumn = dbTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
                    System.out.println("[" + realRow + "],[" + realColumn + "]");
                    Object varDeptno = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 0);
                    Object varDname = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 1);
                    Object varLoc = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 2);
                    System.out.println(varDeptno);
                    System.out.println(varDname);
                    System.out.println(varLoc);
                    //номер строки из модели данных
                    //здесь должна быть выборка объекта из модели по номеру строки и его отображение
                }
            }
        }
    });
    } else if(currentQuery == "SELECT EMPNO ID_СОТРУДНИКА, ENAME ФАМИЛИЯ, JOB ДОЛЖНОСТЬ, MGR ID_РУКОВОДИТЕЛЯ, HIREDATE ДАТА_ПРИЕМА_НА_РАБОТУ, SAL ЗАРПЛАТА, COMM КОМИСИОННЫЕ,"
            + " DEPTNO НОМЕР_ПОДРАЗДЕЛЕНИЯ FROM SCOTT.EMP ORDER BY EMPNO"){
        dbTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {//одинарный шелчок
                int row = dbTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int column = dbTable.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                //путь попроще без selectionMode
                if (row > -1) {
                    int realRow = dbTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    int realColumn = dbTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
                    System.out.println("[" + realRow + "],[" + realColumn + "]");
                    Object varEmpno = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 0);
                    Object varEname = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 1);
                    Object varJob = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 2);
                    Object varMgr = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 3);
                    Object varHiredate = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 4);
                    Object varSal = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 5);
                    Object varComm = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 6);
                    Object varDeptno = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 7);
                    System.out.println(varEmpno);
                    System.out.println(varEname);
                    System.out.println(varJob);
                    System.out.println(varMgr);
                    System.out.println(varHiredate);
                    System.out.println(varSal);
                    System.out.println(varComm);
                    System.out.println(varDeptno);
                    //номер строки из модели данных
                    //здесь должна быть выборка объекта из модели по номеру строки и его отображение
                }
            }
        }
    });
    } else if (currentQuery == "SELECT GRADE НОМЕР_РАЗРЯДА, LOSAL НИЖНЯЯ_ГРАНИЦА_ОКЛАДА,"
            + " HISAL ВЕРХНЯЯ_ГРАНИЦА_ОКЛАДА FROM SCOTT.SALGRADE ORDER BY GRADE") {
        dbTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {//одинарный шелчок
                int row = dbTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int column = dbTable.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                //путь попроще без selectionMode
                if (row > -1) {
                    int realRow = dbTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    int realColumn = dbTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
                    System.out.println("[" + realRow + "],[" + realColumn + "]");
                    Object varGrade = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 0);
                    Object varLosal = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 1);
                    Object varHisal = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 2);
                    System.out.println(varGrade);
                    System.out.println(varLosal);
                    System.out.println(varHisal);
                    //номер строки из модели данных
                    //здесь должна быть выборка объекта из модели по номеру строки и его отображение
                }
            }
        }
    });
    } else {
        dbTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {//одинарный шелчок
                int row = dbTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int column = dbTable.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                //путь попроще без selectionMode
                if (row > -1) {
                    int realRow = dbTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    int realColumn = dbTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
                    System.out.println("[" + realRow + "],[" + realColumn + "]");
                    Object varDeptno = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 0);
                    Object varDname = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 1);
                    Object varLoc = dbtm.getValueAt(realRow, 2);
                    System.out.println(varDeptno);
                    System.out.println(varDname);
                    System.out.println(varLoc);
                    //номер строки из модели данных
                    //здесь должна быть выборка объекта из модели по номеру строки и его отображение
                }
            }
        }
    });
    }
```